# How do I add values to an array in my mongo schema

Tags: javascript, mongodb

My schema looks like this ...

```
  {
    name: String,
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      index: true,
    },
    age: {
      type: Number,
      default: 18,
      required: false,
      minlength: [2, 'Too short'],
      maxlength: [2, 'Too long'],
    },
    role: {
      type: String,
      default: 'client',
    },
    address: String,
    answers: [answerSchema],
  }

const answerSchema = new Schema({
  position: Number,
  slider: Number,
  scale: Number,
})
```

The userId is known. How do I add values to the user.answers array?

I've tried ...

```
const updated = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.params.id },
    { $set: {answers}},
    { new: true }
  )
```

as well as $push ... just I just on't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing: You have to declare `answerSchema` before the main schema because it thrown the error:

```sh
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'answerSchema' before initialization
```

So your code has to be:

```
const answerSchema = new Schema({ ... }) // First
const mainSchema = new Schema({ ... })  // Second
```

Then, into the query, if you use `findByIdAndUpdate` you can use the `_id` directly in the first parameter. Also you can use `$push` to add a new object, like this:

```js
const updated = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
    { $push: {
        answers:{ 
            /* your object to insert here*/
        }
    }},
    { new: true }
  )
```

There is an example how `$push` works [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7WiCPFXJmfk)